# Get select box value of a particular index in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectbox

I have a Select Box where multiple option can be selected. Now I would like to get value of a particular index. How can I do this? For example I have a select box which have following values:

0 - Apple
1 - Orange
2 - Banana
3 - Pineapple

Now I would like to get value of index 2 which is Banana. How can I do this in jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the select box has the same values for value and text, you can get the value for the 2nd select using `eq()` and `val()` like this:

```js
console.log($("select option:eq(2)").val());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
  <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
  <option value="Banana">Banana</option>
  <option value="Pineapple">Pineapple</option>
</select>
```

If the select has numeric values and text, you can get the text "Banana" using `eq()` and `text()`:

```js
console.log($("select option:eq(2)").text());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="0">Apple</option>
  <option value="1">Orange</option>
  <option value="2">Banana</option>
  <option value="3">Pineapple</option>
</select>
```

And in case you want to get the value of the option with the text "Banana" you can do this using `filter()`:

```js
console.log($("select option").filter(function () { return $(this).html() == "Banana"; }).val());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="0">Apple</option>
  <option value="1">Orange</option>
  <option value="2">Banana</option>
  <option value="3">Pineapple</option>
</select>
```